# Nginx location app urls

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to get routing within the nignx config working. I have an app at http://app1:8081 and another app at http://app2:8080. (FYI I'm using docker containers so each app is in its own container) What I have working is for nginx is app1 is point to http://example.com. Where I'm having trouble getting http://example.com/gc to work.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://example.com;

    location /gc/ {
         proxy_pass http://app2:8080/;
    }
    location / {        
         proxy_pass http://app1:8081/;
    }   
}
```

I've tried the proxy_pass with and without trailing / and the location with and without trailing /. I've had an odd result where going to example.com/gc/ would rewrite to example.com/home which didn't work.

I'm was hoping for something that is similar to IIS with application folders under a site. If you have a site that points to example.com and put an application named gc and point it to the application folder.

The end result should be example.com/gc/home renders app2:8080/home.

Any help with my nginx config would be greatly appreciated.